# Post 1.0.3, How much less damage do monsters deal in Act 2+ Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am curious how much a monster hits you for today, relative to what it hit for 2+ days ago.  For example, if a Dragonfly in Act 2 of inferno normally hit you for an average 10k with each attack, do they hit for 8k now?

Please cite source or the evidence on which you base your answer.  (All I am looking for is an estimation of the reduction, THANKS!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Someone did some data mining](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/va9sp/103_inferno_damage_nerfs_mlvl_62_36_mlvl_63_44/), and came to the following numbers:
Monster Level 62(act II): About 36% less
Monster Level 63(act III+IV): About 44% less

Comment: Awesome, thanks for finding that out.  Kind of depressing, but it's good to know.